# CentOS7 / RHEL7 : Automatically restart daemon after yum update

Tags: centos7, rhel7

I built a mail + web server under CentOS7, everything works like as expected : Very well.

But now I would know if it's possible, when I do `yum update`, to automatically restart updated daemons (like such as Debian does).

How can I enable such functionality ?

Thank you very much and have a great day !

Comment: You can make it yourself? Maybe update your yum in a cronjob and also restart your stuff.

Comment: Maybe there's a more proper way to do it ? Also, I don't necessary want to make server update automatically.